# I am getting error :Undefined variable: full_cost in C:\xampp\htdocs\prac\T3\pbookings.php on line 220 And this is my code

Tags: php, mysql

In this code database connections and query are correct. But am getting this error so please me to solve it.

```
$pcost = "SELECT package_name,package_cost FROM new_packages WHERE package_code='$pkg_or_drop' and accommodation='$accom' and occupancy='$occu'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $pcost);
while ($get_cost = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $pack_name = $get_cost['package_name'];
    $full_cost = $get_cost['package_cost'];
}
$total_cost = $no_of_travelers * $full_cost;
?>
```

Comment: How many times did the while loop get executed? I'm guessing none. And it's more obvious if you indent your code well.

Comment: BTW do not build your query like that, read up on SQL injection: https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection (and many other resources here and on the web!)

Comment: Your code does not handle the case where the query returns nothing.  You have to code some logic in there to handle such cases (you could $full_cost = 0; just before the while).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check the number of rows returned is greater than 0, by the following way. And assign some default value to the variable in case if the while loop doesn't get executed.

```
/*Make sure you assign the default value to full cost in case if its doesn't get any value */
$full_cost = 1; 

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($get_cost = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $full_cost = $get_cost['package_cost'];
    }
}
/* Here if the while condition doesnt work then the default full cost will be assigned. Please go ahead and change the value of $full_cost to 0, 1 or your specific one */
$total_cost = $no_of_travelers * $full_cost;
```